# Android Sherlock ActionBar Up button

Tags: android, bitmap, actionbarsherlock

[image]

Near Stream there is a small arrow that takes u to the previous activity when clicked

I want to make the same in my app, I used

```
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

do I need to use `onOptionsItemSelected` ?

The arrow is appearing, but nothing happens once clicked.

And I have two Items in my menu, they appear everywhere where I call `OnCreateOptionsMenu`

this is my item code where I want to to appear only in my last activity, How ?

```
      <item 
android:id="@+id/bAbout"
android:title="About"
android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Comment: Just as an aside the "up" button isn't supposed to, necessarily, take you to the previous activity (that is what the back button does exclusively, although often up and back do the same ) but to a higher level in the conceptual hierarchy of your app. It's fully explained here : http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes you have to implement `onOptionsItemSelected()`. The id for that button is `android.R.id.home`

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case android.R.id.home:
         // Do whatever you want, e.g. finish()
         break;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

> And I have two Items in my menu, they appear everywhere where I call OnCreateOptionsMenu

I'm not sure what the problem here is. Of course you should only implement `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and inflate that menu resource where you want it. Removing `onCreateOptionsMenu()` for all activities which are not supposed to have these options should work.