# Set Android ActionBar Home/Up Button

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I want to put a home button on one of my activities actionbar.

This makes sense... [Android Sherlock ActionBar Up button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996664/android-sherlock-actionbar-up-button)

But this makes more sense:

```
<activity android:name="ItemOne" android:parentActivityName="Dashboard"></activity>
```

Why does an activity let you set a parentActivityName. Shouldn't that enable the up button for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parentActivityName was added in Jelly Bean, ActionBarSherlock is based on Ice Cream Sandwich. The attribute is not supported.

Comment: Gotcha. So... do you think that on a Jelly Bean device, it would enable the up button?

Comment: I'm not sure how it's supposed to work, but it should follow native behavior on JB.